# RESTORE_TRANSATION android in-app code

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, restore

I have a big problem with `RESTORE_TRANSATION` code. I don't understand how I can implement restore in my app. Here is the code:

```
restoButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (BillingHelper.isBillingSupported()) {
                BillingHelper.restoreTransactionInformation(BillingSecurity
                        .generateNonce());

                if( **HERE** ){
                    //restore
                    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(ValoriApp.confName, ValoriApp.mode);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putInt("PRO", 1);
                    editor.commit();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.toast_restore), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(intentback);

                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.toast_norestore), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    Log.e("RESTORE", "restore transation failed(2)");
                }

            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.toast_norestore), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                Log.e("RESTORE", "restore transation failed");
            }

        }
    });
```

I don't know what to put in **HERE** on second `if`. What is wrong?

Comment: May be [this][1] will help your out


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638665/inapp-purchase-restore-transactions-i-am-not-able-to-figure-the-code-out/8666484#8666484

Answer (score 1):

// there no need for the if condition. whats the use of if?

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            if (BillingHelper.isBillingSupported()) {
                BillingHelper.restoreTransactionInformation(BillingSecurity
                        .generateNonce());


                    //restore
                    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(ValoriApp.confName, ValoriApp.mode);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putInt("PRO", 1);
                    editor.commit();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.toast_restore), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(intentback);


            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.toast_norestore), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                Log.e("RESTORE", "restore transation failed");
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: without the "if" how do we know if they've previously purchased? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: i'm confirm the problem :( i don't know I can check if my item "PRO version"(managed) is already purchased